# How Can I Connect an Android App to MySQL Database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, firebase

I want to get data from MySQL database but not with JSON. Is it possible? If it is or not how can I get it? And should I use Firebase wth my app? Probably App will have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Android OS has light-weight database called **SQLite**. You can also go with **Firebase**. SQLite is same as the MySQL database, but it is only used for android os applications. You cant you use MySQL database in android because it has too much size so it needs more RAM and other hardware requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t access a MySQL Database directly via Database Client from Android. This would cause Security Issues because you have to store the password on the Client. The way to go is a REST Api build by your own or using something like Firebase to store your data.